# I need an AppleScript (or maybe JXA) for switching Spaces. I found `kCGWindowWorkspace` but it's gone. Any way to find the Space for any given window?

Tags: desktop, spaces, mission-control, macos, development

I'm working on how to switch between Desktop Workspaces where the hotkey stays the same if I rearrange the order of the Spaces in Mission Control. I also need more than the 16 max hotkeys that Apple allows. I currently have 21 Desktop Workspaces.

The best technique so far, given the lack of API support from Apple, seems to be to create a window, possibly hidden, in each Desktop Workspace. Switching to the right window will activate the desired desktop. (Some people do that with Stickies, but Stickies don't stay on the original desktop after a reboot.)

One piece of the puzzle to switch programatically is I imagine that I will need a way to determine which desktop each hidden window is in.

It seems that from OSX 10.5 to OSX 10.8, Apple provided an API window attribute,`kCGWindowWorkspace`, that would tell you what Mission Control Desktop Workspace any particular window was in; it was simply a fundamental attribute of the window. As it should be, IMHO.

But no longer. It's been deprecated as of OSX 10.11.

Is there any way to do it in Mojave, Catalina, or more recent versions?

If I manually or programmatically activate a particular window that is in another space, I will move to that MC Desktop Space; I can then query to find which space that is. But I would like to, for instance, generate a list of all open TextEdit windows together with which Desktop Workspace they are in, without having to move to each Workspace in turn.

This kind of information is valuable to me because I'm currently working with 21 open Desktop Workspaces, several personal projects, work projects, personal finances, research, various recreations, etc. I'm probably not the only one. But many people max out at about 9 spaces because when they have numbers instead of names, it can become confusing if you can't automate keeping track of them.

The only way I've been able to keep track of them is with a free app, CurrentKey, which lets me assign names to the spaces, names which follow them if they are rearranged, can be changed on the fly, and which can be listed. I generate a Space-choice menu using Keyboard Maestro. CurrentKey also provides one, but it is activated by mouse instead of hotkey, so I prefer KM.

Some kind of workaround for the loss of the `kCGWindowWorkspace` window attribute could be invaluable for actually working effectively with large numbers of Spaces.

Suggestions welcome.

Comment: I've voted to reopen this, but I don't think it's possible. Spaces has always been notoriously intransigent. [It doesn't have any Applescript control either].

Comment: The GitHub utility WhichSpace <https://github.com/gechr/WhichSpace> will put a numeric icon in the toolbar, indicating which Desktop number is the current Space. This can be queried with Applescript:

Comment: tell application "System Events" ¬
to tell process "WhichSpace" ¬
to set temp to (title of menu bar items of menu bar 1)
return item 1 of temp

Comment: The following Swift code will call a function when the Desktop changes. That's also potentially useful.

Comment: NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(forName: 
    NSWorkspace.activeSpaceDidChangeNotification, 
        object: nil, queue: nil, using: 
            <the function you want to handle this event> )